# UWP Community Tookit, SlidableListView remove list item

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using UWP Community Toolkit's `SlidableListItem` control. I've some static list contents in the list view. Now in the UWP Community Toolkit sample app, I find only XAML of the control but not the code file where I can find the event handler of the remove button in the control. I want to write an event in the code file for `RightCommandRequested="SlidableListItem_RightCommandActivated"` so that I can delete those static items in the list view.

The normal code for removing list items in the `ListView` is not working here. Please does anyone know about the code for the event-handler?

Comment: Sorry, I just misspelled it. I'm talking about `SlidableListItem`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now in the UWP Community Toolkit sample app, I find only XAML of the control but not the code file where I can find the event handler of the remove button in the control.

It is right here:

[image]

In the official sample, it uses `ObservableCollection` for the item source of `ListView`, not a static List, the advantage of using this is that this is a dynamic data collection which provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the entire list is refreshed. So, in this sample, it only bind a delegateCommand named `DeleteItem` for `RightCommand` of `SlidableListItem` like this:

```
RightCommand="{Binding DeleteItem, ElementName=Page, Mode=OneWay}"
```

In code behind:

```
private DelegateCommand<Item> _deleteItem = default(DelegateCommand<Item>);

public DelegateCommand<Item> DeleteItem => _deleteItem ?? (_deleteItem = new DelegateCommand<Item>(ExecuteDeleteItemCommand, CanExecuteDeleteItemCommand));

...
private bool CanExecuteDeleteItemCommand(Item item)
{
    return true;
}

private void ExecuteDeleteItemCommand(Item item)
{
    _items.Remove(item);
}
```

As you can see here, it only removes items from the `ObservableCollection`, the relevant `SlidableListItem` of the `ListView` will also be removed.

Now comes to your problem, if you want to use `RightCommandRequested="SlidableListItem_RightCommandActivated"`, it's OK, the `SlidableListItem_RightCommandActivated` will be fired when your swipe from right to left. Problem is your item source, it's a static list, to ensure your `ListView` can get notified when the list is changed, you can either:

1. Copy your static list into a `ObservableCollection` and bind this `ObservableCollection` to the `ItemsSource` of `ListView`, in your `SlidableListItem_RightCommandActivated` event remove the item both in the static list and the `ObservableCollection`.
2. Implement the `INotifyPropertyCanged` interface for your static list.

By the way, you can get the swiped item in the `SlidableListItem_RightCommandActivated` for example like this:

```
private void SlidableListItem_RightCommandRequested(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var slidableitem = sender as SlidableListItem;
    var item = slidableitem.DataContext as Item;
}
```

If you want a demo, you can leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the details information, actually I changed my collections from `List` to `ObservableCollection` And I think I should not use the `SlidableListItem_RightCommandRequested` instead use the DelegateCommand that you just showed. But what are `DelegateCommand` and `Item` in your example? I don't get it in my code.